# php exceptions: should exception be rethrown

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

**UPDATE:**
I want to do something like this: http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFDEV2/Proposal+for+Exceptions+in+ZF2
thats way I need every separate exceptions for each framework component

```
<?php

class ClassA {
    public function doSomething() {
        throw new ClassA\Exception\BadMethodCallException('bad method called');
    }
}

class Application {
    public function MainMethod() {
        $ClassA = new ClassA();
        $ClassA->doSomething();
    }
}

try {
    $Application = new Application();
    $Application->MainMethod();
} catch(\Application\Exception $e) {
    // exception cannot be catched, because ClassA\Exception\BadMethodCallException was thrown
}

?>
```

In my framework eatch components has its own exception classes. So, is it logical that Application throws ClassA exception or should I catch `ClassA\Exception\BadMethodCallException` in `MainMethod` and rethrow as `Application\Exception\BadMethodCallException` like this:

```
<?php
class Application {
        public function MainMethod() {
            $ClassA = new ClassA();
            try {
                $ClassA->doSomething();
            } catch(\ClassA\Exception\BadMethodCallException $e) {
                throw new Application\Exception\BadMethodCallException('message', null, $e);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Well at that rate you're going to have so many `try/catch` statements littered around. What's the motivation for all the exception classes? If it's to allow you to trace the exception, you could print the file/class name in the exceptions, using only one or two exception classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much of a solution for your problem, but having an Exception Class for each part of your App is a bad way to go in my opinion. It doesn't make much sense.

I would just work with the error codes and identify the "Exception thrower" by that.